# IntelliJ IDEA erroneously thinks MouseEvent interface is already declared

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

What is `TS2687:All declarations of 'x' must have identical modifiers.` ? I'm going through TS documentation to learn the language and following code from [Function Parameter Bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) section doesn't work for me

```
interface Event {
    timestamp: number;
}

interface MouseEvent extends Event {
    x: number;
    y: number
}
```

Renaming variables helps. I suspect `MouseEvent` is already defined somewhere but if so I can't understand where it's defined and what to do about it. It seems like it's only IntelliJ IDEA sees an error here but execution of single-file project by npm works correctly.

My config looks like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitThis": true,
     "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
     "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true     /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Typescript, an interface can be declared multiple times, so long as the declarations do not interfere with one another or a class with the same name. The error you're receiving is issued when certain property declarations are interfering with each other, specifically with regards to their modifiers.

For instance, you would receive the same error for this code:

```
class Thing {
    protected timestamp: number; // TS2687
}

// interfaces with the same name as a class effectively extend the class's definition.
interface Thing {
    timestamp: number; // TS2687
}
```

It would appear that either `Event` or `MouseEvent` has already been declared in the context which are are trying to declare it, and that either `timestamp` or `x` or `y` have been declared non-public on those other declarations (specifically, class declarations).

I don't have enough information to tell you if this is your exact problem.

- Check to see if `Event` or `MouseEvent` are declared elsewhere in your project or one of its dependencies, and whether your interface's modifiers interfere with any existing modifiers on those classes.

Comment: It looks like it's only Intelij IDEA that sees an error. I guess it might be a stretch by do you have any ideas why it thinks so ?

Comment: You mean to say that running the `tsc` cli from your project directory does not produce this error? Many popular modules/packages have an `Event` class. I wonder if Intelij is importing those definitions on your behalf, perhaps as part of it's IDE configuration? It may also be that your expected Typescript version is different from Intellij's version. You can probably override this by including a Typescript version in your package managment file (`package.json`, or your package manager's equivalent).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-typescript-to-javascript.html

Comment: `TS2687` is tsc compiler error, so definitely it's not a problem with IDEA, but a configuration issue. TypeScript version being used is configured in *Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript*

Comment: @lena TS2697 How do you think IDEA knows to present the error if it has nothing to do with the compilation? IDEA is the middleman and completely capable of injecting it's own configuration. I simply asked if that may be the case. But hey, if you want to try to solve OPs problem go right ahead.

Comment: TypeScript compiler service is enabled by default in IDEA. And I can know for sure that the error comes from tsc because of the error message and code. IDEA doesn't inject its own configurations - tsc service processes the file based on existing tsconfig.json file(s)

Comment: I have little experience with IDEA, which is why I posed the question. If IDEA is simply allowing the TypeScript compiler service to run against the user-configured `.tsconfig` file, then there is no reason IDEA should be the culprit. I don't know that to be the case, and you haven't actually provided reference to it... in effect, your comment was just "nah, it's definitely not IDEA." IMO It is more helpful to the community when assertions are complimented with references.